# No access to partner - Information could not be retrieved

Tags: google-home, smart-device, nest-device-access

Here is my full error:
Information could not be retrieved. Please contact iandevice to verify that your account has been properly set up. You may need to add the developer email address as a home member in the Google Home app settings.

I have seen several similar questions, but their solution did not help me. I've followed this link to setup: https://developers.google.com/nest/device-access/get-started but got the error when authorizing my account.

My email address is a personal gmail account. I have checked that my email address in the device access console (Top Right) is the same account that is linked to my nest. I have tried several solutions like re-creating the whole GCM project, credentials, etc, or trying with another gmail account.

I have also ensured that my account is added in my Google Home App, tried adding another account and trying but it's the same. Completely lost here after trying everything, does anyone have a solution to this? Thank you.

Just to add on, I have also checked in the OAuth consent screen that I have the same email address listed under email and developer's email. Also tried deleting the whole home and creating a new one, and link my nest to that h ome

Comment: I'm having same issue as well as similar post with same issue: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74694346/pcm-no-access-to-partner-information-could-not-be-retrieved

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for bringing this up. Can you please open a bug in [Public issue tracker](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/new?component=655104&template=1284148) for further debugging and share the same information there. I’m going to follow up with the team and update you through the issue tracker.