# PCM No access to partner: Information could not be retrieved

Tags: nest-device-access

I am stuck on the [authorize account step](https://developers.google.com/nest/device-access/authorize) of the device access quick start guide. I receive an error message saying the information could not be retrieve instead of being redirected. I see a lot of others have ran into the same problem but none of the solutions apply to me.

I am using the same Google account for everything (GCP, Device Access, Home). The account is a member of the home. Has anybody resolved this issue?

I have repeated the steps carefully many times.

Comment: I am running into same issue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Google SDM now supports the the 2nd gen wired Nest Doorbell as of February 15, 2023. I am now able to authorize my account.

Answer (score 0):

For me, it was because I did not agree to Nest terms yet. In Google Home app, I selected setup Nest cam and there it then asked for me to agree to Nest terms. After doing that, I refreshed the browser for the authorization and it worked!

Comment: Unfortunately I don't think this is my issue. My device is already setup as far as I can tell in the Home app. I have a feeling it is because I have the new wired doorbell and the api doesn't work unless I have at least one supported device activated.

Comment: Same problem as @litex2x, I've got only the new Nest Doorbell (wired, 2nd generation) and know that isn't supported by the SDM. But the error message is confusing if it's really because of that.

Comment: Is it one of the new doorbells not supported yet by the SDM API? I've seen people get this error when they have no devices to see.

Comment: Very disappointing this was released without SDM api support. I guess I will just have to wait it out for now.